# Function returning lambda function - where does lambda function get its input from?

Tags: angular, typescript, lambda

Can anyone explain this following lambda function please?

This function should set 'mismatchedFields' to true/false and return it as an object, if `field1` and `field2` of a form, have the same value:

```
function matchingFields(field1, field2) {
    return form => {
        if(form.controls[field1].value !== form.controls[field2].value)
            return { mismatchedFields: true }
    }   
}
```

It is used in Angular forms validators, as follows:

```
export class NewUserComponent {
    private form: any;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.form = fb.group({
            password: '',
            passwordConfirm: ''
        }, { validator: matchingFields('password', 'passwordConfirm')})
    }
}
```

I don't understand where does `'matchingFields'` supply the variable `'form'` to the lambda function returned in the first `'return'`

Can anyone explain the functionality of this lambda function please?

Thanks.

Comment: `form` is no different from the parameters `field1` and `field2` - they are supplied when you call the function. `matchingFields` does not supply the parameter `form` because it does not call the lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set this

```
validator: matchingFields('password', 'passwordConfirm')
```

you call the function `matchingFields` which returns another function from it ( *arrow/lambda function* ). After this call you can consider that you have a function like this which is returned from the `matchingFields`.

```
function someFunction(form) {
   var field1 = 'password';
   var field2 = 'passwordConfirm';

   if(form.controls[field1].value !== form.controls[field2].value)
            return { mismatchedFields: true }
}
```

and in the `formGroup` now you will have something like

```
validator: someFunction
```

You have just set the reference of `validator` to the function `someFunction`, which is the returned one from `matchingFields`. Now this function will be called automatically by `Angular` at the validation stage and the `form` parameter will be passed to the function automatically. This `form` is that on which validation runs.

Comment: I understand that the input parameter 'form' is sent by Angular when invoking 'Validator(form)' ?

Answer (score 2):

The `FormBuilder` invokes the callback down the road (i.e., internally.)

The `matchingFields` definition is simply a generified version of this:

```
…
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.form = fb.group({
    password: '',
    passwordConfirm: ''
  }, {
    validator: form => {
        if (form.controls['password'].value !== form.controls['passwordConfirm'].value) {
          return { mismatchedFields: true }
        }
    }
  })
}
```

So I would image that inside `FormBuilder.group(a, b)` the following takes place:

```
b.validator(this.internalFormReference)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a running example of how it can be called :

```js
// The function from the question
function matchingFields(field1, field2) {
 return form => {
  if (form.controls[field1].value !== form.controls[field2].value)
   return {
    mismatchedFields: true
   }
 }
}

// A simplified version of the FormGroup object
const form = {
 controls: {
  a: {
   value: 'test'
  },
  b: {
   value: 'test2'
  }
 }
};

// as form.a.value !== form.b.value the validator should not be undefined
console.log(matchingFields('a', 'b')(form));
```